# Smash me flat for your conspiracy theories - What am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Weave me into a blanket for a little donkey,
Smash me flat for your conspiracy theory,
I'm a joke that will make you groan,
Under your foot I will make you moan.

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's

> corn.

Weave me into a blanket for a little donkey

> A little donkey is a burrito, and you make corn into a tortilla that is a "blanket" for a burrito.

Smash me flat for your conspiracy theory,

> Not sure.

I'm a joke that will make you groan

> A corny joke will make you groan.

Under your foot I will make you moan

> A corn on your foot is painful.

Comment: conspiracy theory...smashing corn(stalks) flat...

Comment: You got it! See if you can figure out the conspiracy theory part though!

Comment: kayzeroshort: right! Also known as crop circles, hence the conspiracy theory.

Answer (score 4):

I know it should be "corn" but look at this:

Weave me into a blanket for a little donkey

> same with corn and the burrito, we put cheese in it

Smash me flat for your conspiracy theory

> there is an expression "big cheese" for one's boss who you would have to "smash flat" with/for your theory

I'm a joke that will make you groan,

> Again, same as corny, a joke can be cheesy

Under your foot I will make you moan

> Self explaining, cheese + feet = no good

Comment: Kinda feel it whiffs on the conspiracy theory one but other than that it is a pretty amusing alternative